# I look for a jQuery plugin that can manage a photo gallery

Tags: jquery, plugins, thumbnails

I look for a jQuery plugin that can *manage a photo gallery*.

I want *to choose and move some thumbnails from one category (subcategory) to another*.

I need the *pagination* function because some category can have many photos (thumbnails).

Comment: I use PHP, javascript, JQuery, jQuery UI. I would like to use drag'n'drop  method from jQuery UI framework for moving thumbnails.

Comment: This isnt the place for this question. Try googling them.

Comment: I can't look for so plugin with google and plugins.jquery.com site.

Comment: 1. Use blueimp gallery for the gallery.
2. twitter-bootstrap for pagination

Comment: Thanks But I have some doubts about these programs How can I move thumbs from one album (category) to another?